# Sagepay Testing

Tags: model-view-controller, opayo

I am integrating sagepay to my website to take payments. I was wondering is there a way to test the sagepay post back on localhost? Right now when I process payment I get error :

```
*5006: Unable to redirect to vendor's website.*
```

As the Notification host name is set to local host, which isn't accessible through sapgepay website.  So I was wondering is there any other way to test it or Do I have to host my website on some web server. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to host your website on a web server, I'm afraid.